# how to import "genlib.h" into Visual C++ (Ultimate 2013)

Tags: visual-c++

I'm watching Stanford open course "CS106B programming abstractions". In this course , it asks you to use their special library "genlib.h". It takes me two days to import this library , but still can't get it right. My question is how to import "genlib.h " to Visual C++  (Ultimate 2013). here is the course's website:      http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/
        Anyone please help me , I appreciate!!!

```
     #include "genlib.h" 
     #include "simpio.h" 
     #include <iostream> 

     int main() 
     { 
         cout << "Hello,world" << endl; 

         return 0; 
     }
```

The Visual C++ yelled at me : Error :can not open source file "genlib.h" same as "simpio.h"

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the preprocessor can't find the file. Either you need to put `genlib.h` and `simpio.h` in the same directory as your source file, or install them to some other place on your disk and then set up the inclusion paths:

- Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select `Properties`
- Navigate to Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General
- Add the path to `Additional Include Directories`

Comment: Hi,"the_mandrill". I'm really appreciate you give me some hint. However,I tried the second solution, it still said: Error :can not open source file "genlib.h". This is my path to  Additional Include Directories:   C:\Users\Sun\Desktop\cppProjects\cs106lib-0.3.1;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories) And I download this library at [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/progabstrlib/files/)

Comment: The header files in this particular library live in a `headers` subdirectory, so you'll need to add this to your include path.

Comment: Thank you , the_mandrill!! This time the complier didn't yelled me  Error :can not open source file "genlib.h".  However , my little poor program still doesn't work, it said: error LNK1561:entry point must be defined.    I tried created empty project and Window32 Console Application , both said same error. Is that possible the library is out of date? Thank you for your precious time !!

Comment: Sounds like you need to read more about how to build C++ libraries with VisualStudio first.

Answer (score 0):

Little late in the game, but I have started on this course as well.
You can find the libraries here - https://github.com/aj3779672/cprog

I don't use Visual Studio but I think it will find the Header files and C files if you put all of them in same folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).